# Internal property setters in C#

Tags: c#, properties, setter, internal

I'm trying to figure out a good way to approach this.  I have a Customer class which implements the ICustomer interface.  This interface has a number of properties in it:

```
public interface ICustomer
{

   string FirstName {get; set;}
   string LastName  {get; set;}
}
```

I only want certain classes to have the ability to set those properties however; namely, those classes in the project.  So I thought about making the setter `internal`:

```
public class Customer : ICustomer
{

   string FirstName {get; internal set;}
   string LastName  {get; internal set;}
}
```

I'd like to mark that setter as internal in the interface however, so there's no chance someone implements ICustomer and someone outside the assembly modifies those properties. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The properties in the interface should be read only.  It's acceptable for the concrete class that implements the interface to have a setter even if none is defined in the interface.

```
public interface ICustomer
{
   string FirstName { get; }
   string LastName  { get; }
}

public class Customer : ICustomer
{
   public string FirstName { get; internal set; }
   public string LastName  { get; internal set; }
}
```

If it's really important that the setter be exposed through an interface, rather than having the interface being entirely read-only, you can use something like this:

```
public interface IReadCustomer
{
    string FirstName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
}

internal interface IWriteCustomer
{
    string FirstName { set; }
    string LastName { set; }
}

internal interface IReadWriteCustomer : IReadCustomer, IWriteCustomer
{ }

public class Customer : IReadWriteCustomer
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        internal set { _firstName = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        internal set { _lastName = value; }
    }

    string IReadCustomer.FirstName
    {
        get { return FirstName; }
    }

    string IReadCustomer.LastName
    {
        get { return LastName; }
    }

    string IWriteCustomer.FirstName
    {
        set { FirstName = value; }
    }

    string IWriteCustomer.LastName
    {
        set { LastName = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  If I do that however, and the consuming class uses ICustomer it can't get to the setter.

Comment: @larryq  That is the whole point, because the interface is not committing to the setter.  If you want to implement a second internal interface that adds the setter you could.  I often have a series of interfaces:  this is a real example:  `IDimensionedMap` only commits to dimensions of a 2D entity; `IReadMap` with readable properties, `IReadMap : IDimensionedMap` for read only or computed maps, and then `IWriteMap : IReadMap`.   But this is a complex family of extendable utility classes. (These are 2d Hilbert spaces, not Dictionaries, if you are curious.)

Comment: @larryq While I'm not sure if you need it or not, I've added an alternate implementation in which the interface defines an internal set method.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, these are great tips and much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

> I'd like to mark that setter as internal in the interface however, so there's no chance someone implements ICustomer and someone outside the assembly modifies those properties. Is there a good way to do this?

No. Property members are *always* public, unfortunately. Additionally, messing around with access levels on properties where part of it is specified on the interface gets painful, IIRC. What you *can* do is this:

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    string FirstName { get; }
    string SecondName { get; }
}

internal interface ICustomerWithSetMethods : ICustomer
{
    void SetFirstName(string name);
    void SetLastName(string name);
}

public class Customer : ICustomerWithSetMethods
```

Then from the *outside* it'll look like `Customer` only implements `ICustomer`, but from *inside* your code will see that it implements `ICustomerWithSetMethods`.

Unfortunately that doesn't play nicely if your API needs to declare any public methods where you'd *really* like to just declare a return type of `ICustomer`, but you'll actually know that it's always `ICustomerWithSetMethods`.

Assuming you still want to allow multiple implementations, you could potentially go for an abstract class instead:

```
public abstract class CustomerBase
{
    public abstract string FirstName { get; }
    public abstract string LastName { get; }

    internal abstract void SetFirstName(string name);
    internal abstract void SetLastName(string name);
}
```

Now we have the slight oddity that no-one outside the assembly can extend your `CustomerBase`, because there are abstract methods they'd have to override that they can't even *see* - but it does mean you can use `CustomerBase` everywhere in your API.

This is the approach we took in [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) for calendar systems in the end - I [blogged about it](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/03/the-curious-case-of-the-publicity-seeking-interface-and-the-shy-abstract-class/) when I first came up with the plan. I *generally* prefer interfaces to abstract classes, but the benefit here was significant.

Comment: You missed the types and scope on FirstName and SecondName

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with your approach, but I generally implement both the interface and the abstract base classes when maintainability over time is going to be an issue.  Its a bit of extra typing, but tools like Resharper make it easier, and that means you can have more than one abstract implementation when you have a complex family of objects, perhaps one that will be extended outside your own code library.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: It's not a matter of extra typing - I've *love* to be able to put an interface over the top of this; the problem is that you can't declare an internal member in the interface. That's the point of this question. (In the case of Noda Time, I really don't mind 3rd parties not being able to add new implementations. We deliberately hide a lot of the types which *have* to be in abstract member signatures.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I missed that subtlty.  I thought there was a second internal interface extending the first public interface, which is legal.  Generally C# comes closer than any other classic object language to expressing what I want in that paradigm!   My compromise for those cases is also seen in some of the CLR library classes--throwing an IllegalOperationException for the non-supported part of the interface, providing properties that let you test for that first, and documenting the bleep out of it.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: That doesn't help when you need to refer to internal types within the member signatures though, unfortunately... I do seem to hit corner cases like this more than others!

Comment: Yeah, C# doesn't have a `friend` notion like C++ if I remember right from 20 years ago when I knew C++.  Truthfully, I think that is probably the right design decision, but it would have solved this very particular case.